# Creating a new dataframe with Median values (subset by row)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this.[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tthis.png)

For each "NAME" (row name) I want to extract the median value per column.
Ideally, I want the dataframe to look like:

| Name | Value 1 (median) | Value 2 (median) | Value 3 (median) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 7 | 5 | 2 |
| Row 2 | 3 | 1 | 7 |
| Row 3 | 4 | 6 | 1 |

Comment: There are quite literally hundreds of questions on StackOverflow that relate to your request, search for `[r] summarize by group`. If you want to search outside of Stack, then you can (for example) google `"r" "summarize" "group"` (quotes intentional) and will find many howtos and tutorials (and links to Stack questions/answers).

Comment: But for your next question, it is much easier to be able to use data when demonstrating code and/or answers, but many will not transcribe your data from an image into something usable. Please post something we can copy/paste, for instance the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a sample of data we can use.

Answer (score 2):

We can group by 'Name' and get the `median` of all the other columns by `summarise`ing `across` those (`everything()`) columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), median, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(. ~ Name, df1, median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I wanted to specify which columns I want to find the median for using the second function? For example, what If i only wanted to find the median for columns 1-3? (in my actual dataset I do not want to find the median for every column, just columns 1-3

Comment: @NatashaH With `across`, you can use a range of select-helpers.  `everything()`, implioes all the rest of the columns.  If you need only column at positions 1-3, you can specify `1:3` as a range.  But, a word of caution here - position index works better without a grouping variable.  With grouping variable, things are different.  Instead use `names` of those variables in a range ie.. `across(Value1:Value3, .`